# Show that if $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |E_k| < \infty$, then $\displaystyle |\limsup_{k\rightarrow \infty} E_k|=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |E_k| < \infty$, then
      $\displaystyle |\limsup_{k\rightarrow \infty} E_k|=0$.

Where $|*|$ denotes the Lebesgue measure, all sets are assumed to be measurable, and $\limsup_{k\rightarrow \infty} E_k = \bigcap_{k=1} \bigcup_{j=k} E_k$

Been struggling with this one, any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $N$ large, we use that $\limsup E_n$ is an intersection, and subadditivity of the measure:
$$|\limsup E_n|\leq|\bigcup_{n=N}^\infty E_n|\leq\sum_{n=N}^\infty|E_n|$$
and the right-hand side is a tail of a convergent series, so it goes to $0$

Answer (score 0):

If $|\limsup E_k|\neq0$ or equivalently $\limsup E_k\neq\varnothing$ then it contains some element $x$.

Then the set $\{k\mid x\in E_k\}$ is infinite, so there is a subsequence $(E_{k_n})_n$ with $x\in E_{k_n}$ for every $n$ and consequently $|E_{k_n}|\geq1$ for every $n$.

Then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|E_k|\geq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|E_{k_n}|=+\infty$.

Comment: How can you come from the set being nonempty to having a measure greater than zero? Even a countable collection has measure zero!

Comment: @MathematicalMushroom My answer is indeed not okay. The reason of failure is that interpreted $|E|$ as cardinality of $E$. The notation invited me to do that but I should have red your question more carefully. Sorry for that.

Comment: My mistake, I edited the question to include the fact that I was indeed referring to measure.